# Convert a function call to a Expression C#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, expression

I have the following function in which I want to go through the function parameters...

```
    private static void TestExpression(Expression expr)
    {            
        MethodCallExpression methodCall = expr as MethodCallExpression;
        if(methodCall == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("not a function call");

        ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> args = methodCall.Arguments;
        ParameterInfo[] param = methodCall.Method.GetParameters();
        param.ToList().ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p.Name));
    }
```

Just for exemplification I also have a dummy function ...

```
    static int SomeFunc(int a, int b)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

The problem is that I don't know how to convert the function call into a Expression, that is, I don't know how to make the following call

```
TestExpression(/*Something here converting SomeFunc(20, 30) to a Expression*/)
```

I want to mention that I am not interested in other methods to go through the parameters. I tried multiple variants with lambda expressions but with no success...

Comment: I forgot to mention that .Net 3.5 is used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work with your current implementation, you need to explicitly create an expression and extract a body from it. The code would go like this:

```
TestExpression(((Expression<Func<int>>)(() => SomeFunc(1, 2))).Body);
```

but it's not very readable.

EDIT:
More info would be required, like a specific use-case, to try to change the code for more readability.

EDIT:
For more readability, you could use something like this:

```
private static void TestExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
{
    TestExpression(expr.Body);
}
```

That will allow you to call the method like this:

```
TestExpression(() => SomeFunc(1, 2));
```

Of course, you still need to provide default values for arguments. To overcome this, you need to slightly change `TestExpression` overload, but in most cases type inference won't work. You can explore this on your own if you want.

Comment: I already tried this version but it will end up throwing the ArgumentException and that means it is not a valid MethodCallExpression. The use - case is that I want to make a test function(for unit tests) which takes a function(or a delegate), goes through it's parameters and tests that it throws ArgumentNullException if they are null. It's an automation to avoid cumbersome and repetitive tests. I found some examples on the net but they were incomplete or they didn't work. Also, I am pissed that I can't do it with this method and want to know how.

Comment: I tested this locally. Do you see `.Body` at the end of the chain? Indeed, without it, it would't work, because then the expression type would be `Expression<Func<int>>`, which derives from `LambdaExpression`, hence `.Body` to extract the actual expression. For your case, I would introduce another layer of method calls to make it more readable. See my answer edited.

Comment: Thanks, nailed it. In the first test of your solution I forgot to comment out my version of the TestExpression call that was hidden among many comments. So I was actually getting the ArgumentException from my version. Can't see the forest for the ... comments. Thanks again.